# null value in controller from UI in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a  href tag which passes the value to controller.
When control goes to controller method... value is null but 
on the UI, when I hover the mouse on href column ... I can see all values as querystring...

Ex:
 abc.com/notify/2
 abc.com/notify/3
 abc.com/notify/4

Any idea what I am missing due to which value is null in controller

Html:

```
<td style="width:70%">
  <a href="/abc/Notify/<%=ist.SeqID %>">Notify! </a>
</td>
```

Controller Code snippet

```
public ActionResult Notify(int? sID)
{

}
```

Comment: You need to include all your RouteMaps.  If you have only default Route Maps, none of them include a parameter called `sID` only `id`, therefore your method's `sID` will *always* be null.

Comment: And why aren't you using `@Html.ActionLink()` or at a bare minimum `@Url.Action()`?  /sadface

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am looking at the suggestions you have given... and Regarding why I am not using Actionlink or Action... so I am new to MVC... just started working... just now realized that there are other options too from your response.. will look into that as well. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend taking a day or more to read [http://www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc).  Good luck!

Comment: 1 more doubt - 

-- If I match the param name with default route param name (default param name as id) ... it works..
-- If I create a new route and keep the param name same as default route i.e. id ... it works... whereas if I change the name for new route param from id to sId... it fails...

Does this mean that - if I define more then one routes... name of all params should match with default route one ?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Probably because he's using WebForms syntax and not Razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have only the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
);
```

with the method:

```
public ActionResult Notify(int? sID)
{

}
```

The following url:

> /abc/Notify/1

follows the routing method and would assign id=1.  However the method does not have a parameter called id, it has sID which does not match so it becomes null, always.

You can either:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{sid}",
```

or

```
public ActionResult Notify(int? ID)
```

> Does this mean that - if I define more then one routes... name of all params should match with default route one ? –

I'm not fully sure what this means.